# Clear socket.io buffer on disconnect/error

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

1) In disconnected mode I am sending some data to server and on socket error I am displaying message "Please check your internet connection and try again".

2) When socket reconnect it is sending step 1 data to server (As per functionality it should be discarded).

I don't know close/disconnect clears buffer or not and I also want to reconnect automatically when connection is available.
I am creating android app and using socket.io.

Comment: Related info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131629/socketio-stop-re-emitting-event-after-x-seconds-first-failed-attempt-to-get-a-re/32261523#32261523.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to java so this question may look silly.
I am using socket.io.client library (chttps://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)

I got sendBuffer in my Socket class (it is private class variable so can't access it)(src/main/java/io/socket/client/Socket.java)
private final Queue<Packet<JSONArray>> sendBuffer = new LinkedList<Packet<JSONArray>>();

Only public method that has sendBuffer

public Emitter emit(final String event, final Object... args) {
//Lot of code (this code is modifying some priavate class variable, so cant overwrite.

Comment: if (Socket.this.connected) {
 Socket.this.packet(packet);
} else {
 Socket.this.sendBuffer.add(packet);
}

Can you pleae suggest anything to clear sendBuffer in this case ?
I also tried to clone this repostitory and than add it as module but it has lot of other depenceies as well, so getting lot of complie error.

Comment: If you're programming in Java, I can't help further.  Your question did not tag Java (I just added that tag to your question) so I wrongly assumed you were in Javascript.  You will likely have to study the code for the Java implementation to figure out what change you could make (like what I did in the above reference for Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way out to perform it which worked for me, it may be a little tricky and yes the code here is a combination of several answers which I found on StackOverflow.

The trick I used is **to close the socket, make it NULL and then recreate and try to connect it.** 
It helps to clear the buffer and reconnect in a smooth way.

```
ackMessageTimeOut = new AckMessageTimeOut(5000) {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                if (args != null) {
                    if (args[0].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("No Ack")) {
                        Log.d("ACK_SOCKET", "AckWithTimeOut : " + args[0].toString());
                        acknowledgeMessage(null);
                        if (socket != null) {
                            socket.close();
                            socket = null;
                            connectSocket(); // Custom method which creates the socket and tries to connect it.
                        }
                    } else if (args[0].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        cancelTimer(); //cancel timer if emit ACK return true
                        Log.d("ACK_SOCKET", "AckWithTimeOut : " + args[0].toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        socket.emit("sendMessage", message, ackMessageTimeOut); // You can apply it on whatever event you want.
```

AckMessageTimeOut class  is as below:

```
private class AckMessageTimeOut implements Ack {

        private Timer timer;
        private long timeOut = 0;
        private boolean called = false;

        AckMessageTimeOut(long timeout_after) {
            if (timeout_after <= 0)
                return;
            this.timeOut = timeout_after;
            startTimer();
        }

        private void startTimer() {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callback("No Ack");
                }
            }, timeOut);
        }

        private void resetTimer() {
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
                startTimer();
            }
        }

        void cancelTimer() {
            if (timer != null)
                timer.cancel();
        }

        void callback(Object... args) {
            if (called)
                return;

            called = true;
            cancelTimer();
            call(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void call(Object... objects) {

        }
    }
```