# why did the socket.io clients resend offline messages when reconnect succcess?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am doing a chat room using socket.io. When a client is offline(just turn off the wifi), I still send a message(named offline messages A) to the server through the message will not send success. After a while, the client will receive the disconnect event, ignore that, I still send messages(named offline messages B) to the server. After doing above, I turn on the wifi, and the client will reconnect success. Ok, the problem is that the server will receive all the offline messages(A, B) after the client reconnects success. I can not figure this out, how it goes from offline to reconnect success of the socket.io.

I know that the offline messages B is stored in the sendBuffer as described in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131629/socket-io-stop-re-emitting-event-after-x-seconds-first-failed-attempt-to-get-a-r). And the client will resend the messages in the sendBuffer when it reconnects success, but why the offline messages A still can send to the server success? I have coded to show this problem

```
/*
* Client side
*/
onClickSend = (value) => {
    console.log('send message:', value)
    this.socket.emit('chatMessage', value);
}
connect = () => {
    if (!this.socket) {
        console.log('connecting...')
        this.socket = io(url, {
            query: {
                clientId: this.clientId
            },
            forceNew:true,
        })
    }
    this.socket.on('connect',()=>{
        console.log('connected');
    })

    this.socket.on('error',(err)=>{
        console.log('error happen：',err);
    })
    this.socket.on('disconnect',(reason)=>{
        console.log('disconnect event：', reason);
    })
    this.socket.on('reconnect',(e)=>{
        console.log('reconnect success：' , e);
    })
}

/*
* Server side
*/
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const PORT  = 40001;
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    const clientId = socket.handshake.query.clientId;
    console.log('client come...', clientId)

    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
        console.log('user connects socket');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', (reason)=>{
        console.log('event disconnect: ', reason, clientId)
        socket.removeAllListeners()
        socket = null
    })
    socket.on('error', (err)=>{
        console.log('error happen: ', err, clientId)
    })

    // the server will receive all the offline messages(message A, B)
    // send after the network is down when the client 
    // reconnect success.
    socket.on('chatMessage', (message)=>{
        console.log('receive message: ', message, clientId)
        io.emit('chatMessage', message)
    })

});


http.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:', PORT);
});
```

As I see, the server will not receive the offline message, but the server receives all the offline messages when the client reconnects success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [socket.io stop re-emitting event after x seconds/first failed attempt to get a response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131629/socket-io-stop-re-emitting-event-after-x-seconds-first-failed-attempt-to-get-a-r)

Comment: there are some differences with that questions, mine is more brief, and  the answer in that question can not solve my question

Answer (score 0):

Base of [socket.io code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L150) on emit:

```
if (this.connected) {
    this.packet(packet);
} else {
    this.sendBuffer.push(packet);
}
```

so, `offline messages A` will be pushed to sendBuffer, then `offline messages B` will be pushed to sendBuffer, then when socket connect again, sendBuffer will be send to server.